# why do we have to select a database when we connect to a database?

Tags: database, pdo

Why do we have to select a database when we connect to a database?

For example, when we use `PDO` to connect a database, we must define a database name,but in mysqli we have a function `mysqli_select_db()` to select another database after connecting…

So is there a function like `mysqli_select_db()` in `PDO` to achieve select db after connection?

Comment: Short answer is no since the database name is part of the DSN that is used when creating the PDO object. If you need to work with more than one database at a time create a new PDO object.